# Get variable from inside JavaFX TreeTable CellFactory Callback

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, treetableview

I'm working with a JavaFX TreeTableView containing items of type BillingTableRow. I want the columns to be styled based on a value given by a method getType() in BillingTableRow, but I can't seem to access it from inside the callback that I'm trying to set up. Here is my code:

```
Callback<TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double>, TreeTableCell<BillingTableRow, Double>> eveningCallback = new Callback<TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double>, TreeTableCell<BillingTableRow, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeTableCell<BillingTableRow, Double> call(TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> p) {
            return new EditableTreeTableDoubleCell() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    BillingTableRow row = (...)// Get attached BillingTableRow for current tree table row.
                    if (row.getType() == 0) {
                        setText(null);
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    };
    eveningColumn.setCellFactory(eveningCallback);
```

What should I replace (...) with in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

[`BillingTableRow row = getTreeTableRow().getItem();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableCell.html#tableRowProperty)

Both `TableCell` and `TreeTableCell` define a `tableRow` property that gives the cell displaying the entire row to which the current cell belongs. For a `TreeTableCell<S,T>`, `getTreeTableRow()` will return a `TreeTableRow<S>` which is a subclass of `Cell<S>`. This means it has a `getItem()` method whose return type is `S`, i.e. the item that represents the data for the entire row.